# jqwidgets grid grouping with aggregate and editable

Tags: jqwidget

When grid is grouping and column has aggregate and

```
editale:true
```

when user change column data sum in grouping section does not update but sum in total row does update...

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4zAHJ/743/)

I want when user change column data sum row in grouping section and sum in total row will be update...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#grid").on('cellvaluechanged', function (event) 
 {

      $("#grid").jqxGrid('refreshgroups');
        $("#grid").jqxGrid('expandallgroups');
 });
```

With this code aggregate data update after finish change column value